# Receive "Siri remote" event in background on tvOS

Tags: background, avplayer, tvos

I have made a radio player for tvOS and I wan't the audio stream to keep playing while in background. All this works nicely and was pretty easy.

However I would like to stop the stream/audio if "play/pause" button is pressed while in background. But I can't figure out how to do this. 
I only want it to stop, not pause. This is how Apple Radio works.

I'm handling all my input with Press events and Actions, setup from the interface builder. 
What I've found so far is how it works on iOS, and I've been suggested to use, but remoteControlReceivedWithEvent is never called (not even in foreground).

Any help on this is highly appreciated, especially if you've had the luck with implementing it yourself ;)

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {}
```

Comment: Does TvOS support background remote control event delivery for developer apps?    I just did a quick search and couldn't find any documentation that states it's possible (Apple Radio doesn't count since it's an Apple product that isn't restricted in any way).  I'm not saying you can't, I just haven't personally seen anything stating that you can.

Comment: @earthtrip - No I haven't found any documentation stating that this should be possible either. Just thought that since background mode is available it would be possible to control it too. 
I've posted the question on the Apple forum and hopefully one of their engineers can clear this out. I will post the answer here when I have it. 
They should however add this to the SDK, it's not very nice that the users can't stop the music playing in background from other than Apples own app. But well, Apple TV at the moment is more like an open beta. An expensive one too :)

Comment: Agreed on all counts ;)

Comment: @ChrissyMcBeal Did you get any answers? Is it possible to receive remote events while in background? I was able to get it to work while in foreground with a gesture recognizer.

Comment: @TatarasanuVictor no I didn't receive an answer on the tvOS forum, so I don't think I will. 
I did submit my app and it cleared the review process and is now in the App Store. So my guess would be that it isn't possible yet since they let it clear. Hopefully it will be possible/easier in the future :)

Comment: Hi, @ChrissyMcBeal, any updates? Any updates? I'm working on a similar project, so we may share some knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thisI was able to get working using `MediaPlayer's` `MPRemoteCommandCenter`

```
func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
    let remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter()

    let pauseCommand = remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand
    pauseCommand.enabled = true
    pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: "pauseEvent")
}

func pauseEvent() {
    pause()
}
```

Comment: Spoke with an Apple Engineer during one of their TV tech talks and can confirm that this is correct.

Comment: Also, as per the docs on `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents`.. "In iOS 7.1 and later, use the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter object to register for remote control events. You do not need to call this method when using the shared command center object." Despite an obvious reference to iOS, I would expect this to apply in tvOS development as well

Comment: This is great, I've just briefly tested it since I'm working on other projects. Very cool, thanks for sharing.